# Execute commands on remote machine via PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssh

To give background on my environment:

I have 3 machines A, B & C

A = Webserver, running a php website which basically acts as an interface for B & C

B = Linux Ubuntu machine, i have root access, SSH and all the needed goodness to work on the machine via a SSH client (i have a .ppk private key file for this server)

C = MySql Database server running on Linux

I can successfully execute queries from A (php) on C (Mysql) and return the results. But now im trying to execute linux commands on B from A.

Eg.

I have a script thats running on B and would like to execute a command from A (php) to show the status of the script.

In Command line to do this is easy - ./SomeScript status

But i want to show the status of this script in the website im hosting on Server A.

Even just check the uptime of Server B on Server A.

Is this in anyway possible. i have googled forever as it seems but im not getting anywhere, Im not too phased if the connection is secure or not as this is a closed network with no outside access to this network.

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not place a script on `B` that gives specific information such as uptime, and can allow running specific programs? You will want to have the script check that the IP is indeed from server `A` though.

Comment: Thanks, see that i can do, the problem im having is to display the results from a specific script on B on a php page on A

Comment: The results are likely dumped as some sort of text or html file. After the output file is produced on B, scp it to A.

Comment: But how do i connect to B in the first place from A? and then execute the query / command especially with the public key i have?

Comment: Do you have root access and ability to run commands on `A`?

Comment: Yes i do. i have root access on A & B

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run SSH commands through PHP on server A to server B.

Here is how to run ssh commands with the command line in linux: http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=fvwp&v=YLqqdQZHzsU

In order to run commands on linux with PHP use the [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command.

I hope this will get you started looking in the right direction.

Look at these two posts for automating the password prompt

- https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password
- https://serverfault.com/questions/187036/execute-ssh-command-without-password

Here is a quick example with ***non-working*** code to get you thinking:

```
<?php

    $server = "serverB.example.org";
    //ip address will work too i.e. 192.168.254.254 just make sure this is your public ip address not private as is the example

    //specify your username
    $username = "root";

    //select port to use for SSH
    $port = "22";

    //command that will be run on server B
    $command = "uptime";

    //form full command with ssh and command, you will need to use links above for auto authentication help
    $cmd_string = "ssh -p ".$port." ".$username."@".$server." ".$command;

    //this will run the above command on server A (localhost of the php file)
    exec($cmd_string, $output);

    //return the output to the browser
    //This will output the uptime for server B on page on server A
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($output);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The recommended flow is to run a command on server A to SSH to server B

Comment: thanks for the link, however i want to send ssh commands directly from php to a remote linux machine?

Comment: @Stroes please see edited answer with an example to get you thinking in the right direction. This will run the ssh commands directly from php to a remote machine and return the response.

Comment: @amaster i have execute the same code in my lamp but it's not returing output.if i use same command in my bash it gives the output.

Comment: The referenced youtube video is unavailable

Answer (score 2):

Use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html) to securely SSH or SCP to remote servers

Install with
`composer require phpseclib/phpseclib`

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib\Net\SCP;

// Load your private key
$key = new RSA();
$key->loadKey('private key string');

// Connect to the server
$ssh = new SSH2('ip_address', 'port', 'timeout');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    throw new Exception("Unable to connect");
}

// Run a remote command
echo $ssh->exec('whoami');

// SCP put a string
$result = (new SCP($ssh))->put('remotePath', 'content to put');
// SCP put a file
$result = (new SCP($ssh))->put('remotePath', 'localPath', SCP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);

// SCP get a file
$result = (new SCP($this->ssh))->get('remotePath', 'localPath');

// $result is true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [SSH2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) to execute commands on remote machine. You can use `pecl` to install it easily. After that, you may use `ssh2_exec()` function to execute your commands and `ssh2_fetch_stream()` function to get stderr. Example codes are listed below:

```
// start connection
$connection = ssh2_connect("your remote ip address", your port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection,"your user name","your passwd");

// connection established, start to execute codes
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "your command");  
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

// block 2 streams simutaneously
stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
stream_set_blocking($stream,true);

// write stdout and stderr to log file
file_put_contents("your log file-path", date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\nError: ".stream_get_contents($errorStream)."\nOutput: ".stream_get_contents($stream), FILE_APPEND)

// close 2 streams   
fclose($errorStream);
fclose($stream);

// close remote connection
ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
```

Cheers.