# How to execute a shell script on a remote linux machine using php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script test.sh on a remote ubuntu machine with IP:192.168.1.1 in the/home/ directory and I have my apache2 and php installed in ubuntu machine with IP:192.168.1.2.

I need to execute the shell script on remote node from webserver machine, is there any way I can do that using a php script?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028536/execute-commands-on-remote-machine-via-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute commands on remote machine via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028536/execute-commands-on-remote-machine-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

I think the fast way you can do (but not the secure way) is set up an Web server on the another server, and create a PHP script there to call the bash script. So on the server 192.168.1.1 you call the script php.

But i think the best way to do that, is when you want call this is script, put the request in some queue (could be on the database), on the other server you create a Python or PHP script to consume this queue and run the bash script. This Python/PHP script will be executed via Cron. So in this way you are not able to call the script directly like the first solution. This is the secure way.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell, through SSH if needed. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

May i suggest triggering the induvidual commands rather than a script. That way you can handle the return without having to build exception handling in bash.

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
    //get a shell
    $shell = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getRemoteHost('192.168.1.1')->getShellBySsh('username', 'secretPassword');

    //trigger your script
    $return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/home/test.sh');

    echo $return1;//the return from your script.
```